# How to get path of current directory in Web Application

Tags: java, tomcat, web-applications, path, getproperty

While I try to get path of current dir like bellow in my project it gives the location of where eclipse is downloaded.

```
String Cuurentdir= System.getProperty("user.dir");
```

I want path of my project dir.

Note- Using tomcat as a server.

Comment: Sounds like this might be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378).  If you want to read static data files, you probably want to place them inside your web application and use [Class.getResource](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Class.html#getResource(java.lang.String)) to read them.

Answer (score 0):

String workingDir = (File)servletContext.getAttribute(ServletContext.TEMPDIR);

Comment: This gets you the (spec-required) "temporary directory" for the web application. It may have no relationship to the on-disk deployment of the web application, although it often does.